# How to connect ViewModels to their appropriate Views dynamically?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF application which has a **MainView.xaml** Window which loads **numerous page objects** at runtime, loads them into **ViewModels**, and displays them **dynamically in the menu**.

My MainViewModel has an **ObservableCollection** of **ViewModels** and I bind these each to their appropriate **Views** in the MainView.xaml file.

However, is there a way to **automate** this so I don't have to make these manual entries each time I add a page?

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PageItemManageCustomersViewModel}">
        <v:PageItemManageCustomersView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PageItemManageEmployeesViewModel}">
        <v:PageItemManageEmployeesView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PageItemReportsViewModel}">
        <v:PageItemReportsView/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

Isn't this something that a "**ServiceLocator**" or "**Container**" should be doing, hooking up the Views to the ViewModels? I've read that the above is a **common way** to match up the ViewModels and Views in the MVVM pattern, but it comes across as a **bit static** to me. Would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: There's an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768304/wpf-mvvm-convention-over-configuration-for-resourcedictionary

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use a class for resolving ViewModels based on some key.  You can then use this in your main view to resolve the correct viewmodel for your controls.

```
public static class ViewModelFactory
{
 public ViewModelBase Create(string someKeyHere)
 {
    //Some logic to resolve a view model
 }
}
```