# How to bind elements in separate xaml files?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a MainWindow.xmal which has two TabItems:

```
<TabItem Header="Config" ... />
<TabItem Header="Results" ... />
```

I have a separated Config.xaml file for the Config TabItem which has a ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="UrlConfig" ... />
```

I have another separated Results.xaml file for the Results TabItem which has a TaxtBlock:

```
<TextBlock Name="Url" .../>
```

The problem is that I'd like to bind the selected value in the ListBox to the TextBlock. How can I do that? Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to work with MVVM, but if not you can implement it with XAML only:

Use sepparate resource like "Bridge" 'Config' and 'Results'

Config.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Key="Config">
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectedValue}, Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}" >
<System:String>Minsk</System:String>
<System:String>London</System:String>
<System:String>NY</System:String>
</ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

Results.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Key="Results">
<Label Name="Url" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectedValue}, Path=Y}" />
</UserControl>
```

Code of window with TabControl:

```
<Window.Resources>
<!--"Bridge" resource, here will be your own type-->
<X x:Key="SelectedValue" Y="Minsk"></X>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
<TabControl>
<TabItem Header="Config" Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Config}"/>
<TabItem Header="Results" Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Results}"/>
</TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in [mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish) way you can bind those to a property on your viewmodel and set the [DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853586/what-is-the-best-approach-to-assign-data-context-using-mvvm) for to that viewmodel