# WPF composite Windows and ViewModels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a WPF `Window` which contains few `UserControls`, those controls contain another. And now, what is the most principal way how to create `ViewModel` for this Window and where to bind it.

I do expect that one firstly needs to create `ViewModel` for each of sub-controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

### Inject the VM

I would recommend this method.

If your window is created in the `App` class like

```
var window = new MyWindow();
window.Show();
```

I would assign the VM before showing the window:

```
var window = new MyWindow();
window.DataContext = GetDataContextForWindow();
window.Show();
```

If one of your controls needs an own view model assign the VM wile creating the control instance.

### DataBind

If you want to set the VM of a control you can bind the `DataContext` property to an VM instance provided by the surrounding VM.

```
<Controls:MyControl DataContext={Binding MyControlsVm} />
```

### Code Behind

You may set the VM using the init method in code behind like

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = CreateViewModel;
}
```

You may use a trick if you don't want to create a VM for your main page:

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

and just use the code behind class as VM.

Answer (score 1):

I see the view as a visual representation of the ViewModel so I like WPF picking the view based on the instance of the ViewModel it wants to render.

I call this the View Locator pattern, I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768304/wpf-mvvm-convention-over-configuration-for-resourcedictionary#answer-789315)  to instantiate my view because I have found it to be very simple to implement.

It basically puts an entry in the `ResourceDictionary` of your app that tells WPF to use an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx#exampleToggle) to look up and instantiate the `View` when it comes across a `ViewModel`.

**So a working example would be:**

In your app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In resources.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModelBase}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ViewModelConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Set the `DataContext` of your startup Window Control e.g.

```
public MainWindow : Window
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

And you're pretty much done. So if you have a `MainViewModel` like so:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public ChildViewModel1 Child1 {get;set;}
  public ChildViewModel2 Child2 {get;set;}
}
```

and you have a `UserControl` that resolves to your `MainViewModel` like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainView">
  <StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Child1}"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Child2}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

So your `ViewModelConverter` will return an instance of the appropriate View without any extra effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

On the child controls issue, why wouldn't one of the properties of the root view model be an instance of the child view model that you would pass onto the child control? The other option would be a converter that converts the non-view model based property into an instance of the child view model (like an adapter pattern).

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in the sample applications of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. They show how composite Views and ViewModels can be instantiated and how they interact which each other.

Comment: You have not provided any answer here, and the link you provide is simply to your project, not to any specifically helpful page.